# How can i randomly sample dates for a fixed number in each year without replacement?

Tags: python

I use the following script to generate a  Datetiem series

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def random_dates(start, end, n=10000):
    
    start_u = start.value/10**9
    end_u = end.value/10**9

    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

start = pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2021-12-31')
DD=random_dates(start, end)
df=pd.DataFrame(DD, columns=['t_r'])
```

Then I use this command to randomly select equal observations for each year

```
mod_y = mod_cat['tim'].groupby([mod_cat['tim'].dt.year,], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1293))
```

**Problem:**

However, the output include the duplicate observations, to remove duplicate observations, I use the option replacement=False, but it didn't work so far:

```
mod_y = mod_cat['tim'].groupby([mod_cat['tim'].dt.year, replace=False], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1293))
```

May someone suggest how can I fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: You can first remove duplicates from dataframe using df.drop_duplicates() method then select the random samples.

Comment: If I remove duplicate later than total observations will no more be equal for each year. It is mandatory to have an equal number of observations in each year.